# How to handle multiple request to same Web Worker

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

I have created a web worker which process a large data. following are code implementation:

worker.js

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  console.log('Message received from main script');
  for(var i=0; i<999999999; i++){
    // computation here
  }
  console.log('Posting message back to main script');
  self.postMessage('You said: ' + e.data);
}, false);
```

Main Script

```
var myWorker;
if (window.Worker) {
  if(typeof(w)=="undefined"){
    myWorker = new Worker("scripts/controllers/workers.js");
  }
}
myWorker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    console.log('Message received from worker'+ e.data);
}, false);

function callWorker(someData){
  myWorker.postMessage(someData);
}
callWorker(someData);//first time call - by user click
callWorker(someOtherData);//second time call - again user click (don't want to disable button)
```

in this case i don't want to execute `callWorker` multiple times.
what i want is, if `callWorker` is currently executing and mean while a second request raise for `callWorker`, then first request should terminate and second request should process(latest request should process).

How can i achieve this? Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

You can try terminating the worker and re-initiating it, I guess.
When you call the terminate method, it will terminate immediately without waiting the operations to finish.

```
myWorker.terminate();
myWorker = new Worker('worker.js');
```

Answer (score 1):

> if callWorker is currently executing and mean while a second request raise for callWorker, then first request should terminate and second request should process(latest request should process).

I'm afraid you can not achieve this without terminating the worker. Instead of trying to terminate the current process, I think you should wait until it finish then send the next message right after that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to the party here but i just wanted to share my solution:

I had the same issue and in my case waiting would take too long and creating a new worker wasn't efficient enough.

My solution was to :

1. execute the task in the worker in increments.
2. post back to the main thread and "ask" if it should continue.
3. The main thread responds with a flag indicating if we worker should continue the current task or if it should interrupt/start over with new data.

The worker code:

```
self.addEventListener("message", function (e) {

    var args = new Int16Array(e.data);

    if (args[0] === 1) {//Start new task/start over. 

        ExecuteTask(args);
        self.postMessage("CONTINUE?");

    }else if (args[0] === 2) {//Continue 

        ExecuteTask(args);
        self.postMessage("CONTINUE?");
    }else{
       self.postMessage("TASK_TERMINATED");
    }
}
```

Main thread:

```
myWorker.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
    if (e.data === "CONTINUE?") {

        // ask the worker to start over with new data
        if (newTask) { 
            myWorker.postMessage(newDataMessage);
        }
        //No new tasks. Let the worker know it can continue. 
        else{
            myWorker.postMessage(continueMessage);
        }
    } else if (e.data === "TASK_EXECUTED" || e.data === "TASK_TERMINATED"  ) {
        workerIdle = true; //let main thread know it can execute the next new task instead of queueing it up.
    }                   
});
```